# WebClient - UnsupportedMediaTypeException

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient

I have this code :

```
ResponseEntity<DTODemo> responseEntity = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8051/callAPI/")
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(DTODemo.class)
                .block();
```

It work, when my api return an object `DTODemo`.
But, the API can return with code HTTP 404 a message in the body ( type **String**).
I have this exception :

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported for bodyType=com.example.demo.DTODemo
```

I try many of things but i haven't found a good solution.

Any idea to solve my problem using **retrieve** and not **exchange** ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using `retrieve()` you are not able to access any response information except a body. Therefore there is no way to handle "bad" scenarios in a short simple manner.
Is it really forbidden to use `exchange()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67471061 - does it help?

Comment: Because exchange is now deprecated in Spring.

Comment: I found a solution with this code :  
 .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class, ex -> {
     ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
     return Mono.empty();
    })

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the set of acceptable media types, as specified by the Accept header. For example,

```
ResponseEntity<DTODemo> responseEntity = webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8051/callAPI/")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(DTODemo.class)
                .block();
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to create a custom Exception class DtoNotFoundException for instance and surround your code with try/catch block and catch the UnsupportedMediaTypeException the  throw your custom exception so you can catch it in any other piece of code and do whatever you want

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Dto not found")
public class DtoNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public DtoNotFoundException() {
    }

    public DtoNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

then your code can be like that :

```
try{
    ResponseEntity<DTODemo> responseEntity = webClient.get()
                    .uri("http://localhost:8051/callAPI/")
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(DTODemo.class)
                    .block();
}catch(UnsupportedMediaTypeException e){
    throw new DtoNotFoundException("Dto not found");
}
```

so if you have a scenario using your code you can catch your custom exception and take an action like returning 404 response code with the exception message

```
     @GetMapping("/dto")
    ResponseEntity<?> getDto() {
        try {
            var dtoUseExample = this.yourService.yourClientFunction() // request done;
        } catch (DtoNotFoundException e) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```